# Railo logfile rotation management

Tags: railo, cfml

On my Railo server the logfiles are rotated when 5 MB. I want to increase that size or I want to keep more logfile backkups. How do I do that? What config file did I miss?

Comment: Did you ever get this question answered?  If so, could you post the answer so that others finding this question can see it.

Comment: I didn't get an answer yet and I didn't find it myself either.

Comment: In that case, I think it depends on the application server that you are using. What are you using, Tomcat, JRun, etc.?  I use Adobe CF but as far as I understand things for Railo should be similar.  Also, under ACF there are two different log file locations.  One for the application server (JRun) and one for CF itself.  The JRun log file configuration is located in the `jrun.xml` file.  The CF log file configuration is contained within the CF administrator.  Which log files are you dealing with in your scenario?

Answer (score 1):

There is no UI for this at the moment as far as I know but they have a lot of options under the hood.

The best way to configure this is to look in your website's WEB-INF/railo-web.xml.cfm file. There you can see a block that says:

```
<logging>
    <logger .../>
</logging>
```

There are many options but for logger appender="resource" (i.e. append to file) that you can see in the comment inline in the file, which currently says (on my version which is Railo 4.2.0.007 beta)

```
Resource:
Logs error to a resource (locale file, ftp, zip, ...)
- path: path to the locale file
-charset (default:resource charset): charset used to write the file
- maxfiles (default:10): maximal files created
- maxfilesize (default:1024*1024*10): the maxial size of a log file created
```

So for your use case you should add something like:

```
<logging>
    <logger appender="resource" maxfilesize="5242880" appender-arguments="path:{railo-config}/logs/remoteclient.log" layout="classic" level="info" name="remoteclient"/>
    <logger appender="resource" maxfilesize="5242880" appender-arguments="path:{railo-config}/logs/requesttimeout.log" layout="classic" name="requesttimeout"/>
    <logger appender="resource" maxfilesize="5242880" appender-arguments="path:{railo-config}/logs/mail.log" layout="classic" name="mail"/>
    <logger appender="resource" maxfilesize="5242880" appender-arguments="path:{railo-config}/logs/scheduler.log" layout="classic" name="scheduler"/>
    <logger appender="resource" maxfilesize="5242880" appender-arguments="path:{railo-config}/logs/trace.log" layout="classic" name="trace"/>
    <logger appender="resource" maxfilesize="5242880" appender-arguments="path:{railo-config}/logs/application.log" layout="classic" level="info" name="application"/>
    <logger appender="resource" maxfilesize="5242880" appender-arguments="path:{railo-config}/logs/exception.log" layout="classic" level="info" name="exception"/>  
</logging>
```

(I haven't tested the maxsize calc so your milage might vary)